# Android Customize Calendar?

Tags: android, android-fragments, calendar, android-calendar

I have a functional app that has been on the app store for a while, but I'm looking to make a design change. I would like to make a calendar that customizes based on user input. I have tried googling for answers, but not quite sure what I'm looking for.

The way the app currently works is there is an expandable list view, and each item goes to a new layout with three fragment tabs, monday, wed, fri. It also passes an intent, so it knows what week was selected. Based on the week selected, the three fragments populate recycler views with data.

Basically what I want to change, is there will be a list view for the user to select a 4 week workout. I want this workout to then fill the calendar, starting with the nearest monday(so an event will be added to every monday, wed, and friday for 4 weeks from when they click the item on listview. I then want it so when they click on the item in the calendar(for example monday), a new page or fragment opens with the same recyclerview that I currently have displaying the data.

I think I know how to populate the calendar based on what workout they clicked on using Caldroid. My problem is, I don't know how to save it so when they go back to that date on the calendar a month later, it's saved, rather then re-loading the workout again.

If anyone has any tips, keywords to search for, or links to tutorials or other questions, I greatly appreciate it. 
Thanks!